# Why an HTML element being changed to "position: relative" will cover up other elements?

Tags: css, z-index

I have a div 300 x 200px, and put some words in it with 180px font-size.

Below it, there are 2 images.

So naturally, the images cover up the words, because the images are at a later stage of the document, so it will cover up previous elements.  (if the HTML elements are viewed as in a tree structure, then it is the order of depth-first-search)

But once I changed the CSS of that div to `position: relative`, then the words will cover up the images partially. (`O` will cover up the images only where there is a stroke of the letter, the space inside `O` will still show the images through)

I thought only by changing the z-index can I make it cover up the images?  The words are still in the normal flow of the document... is there a special rule that says position: relative is supposed to cover up the other non-positioned elements?

Comment: Without some code, it's hard to tell, but it probably has something to do with stacking context and stacking level.  [This page](http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Overlapping_And_ZIndex) has a very good description of the effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, positioning, z-index and floating all have an influence on the relative stacking of elements. And inheritance of these properties from ancestors.

You'll find a good tutorial/explanation on Mozilla's website: [Understanding CSS z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/understanding_css_z-index) and a tool to visualize and play with on tjkdesign's site: [How z-index works!](http://tjkdesign.com/articles/z-index/teach_yourself_how_elements_stack.asp) (the related article is shorter than mozilla's one btw ;))
IE (used to) behave(s) ... differently (at least IE<8 edit: not IE9+ and Edge)